# Using fields from an @Embedded Hibernate object to specify id

Tags: hibernate

I'm trying to determine if there is a way I can use fields from an embedded object in an ID.

Here's a simplified version of the classes that I have.

```
@Embeddable
class Entry {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;

    private Entry() {...}

    // getters and setters

    // public static factory to generate instance of Entry
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Entry_X")
class EntryX {

    // I want EntryX to use fields 'a' and 'b' on Entry for its ID

    @Embedded private Entry entry;

    public EntryX() {...}
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Entry_Y")
class EntryY {

    // I want EntryY to use fields 'a', 'b', and 'c' on Entry for its ID

    @Embedded private Entry entry;

    public EntryY() {...}
}
```

I do not have the ability to modify the 'Entry' class, as it's generated as part of an external process. Any change requests to the generator would be at least 1 iteration away from being implemented, so I have to work with what I have at the moment.

Edit: I told a small lie above. I can make some minor changes to Entry. I can add annotations to the class and its methods, through the generator. I can't do things like change the access type of Entry's fields and members.

Entry's constructor is private at the moment, so I can't use a @MappedSuperclass and extension approach.

It seems the @Embeddable approach almost gets me there, but I just can't find a way to properly construct the id for EntryX and EntryY

Any help would be greatly appreciated